# Try to generalize 3 separate functions in 1 JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a very simple project in JavaScript. It's a web application that lets you see colors using 3 sliders and converts the value to hexadecimal.
I would like to know if there is any way to generalize all the functions to add and remove color points.

I have these 3 functions that allow to add color with a click on a button (one for color, so Red, Green, Blue):

```
//Functions to add value to color
function addcolorpointred(){
 document.getElementById("red_value").stepUp(xstep);
 rgb[0] = red_value.valueAsNumber;
}

function addcolorpointgreen(){
 document.getElementById("green_value").stepUp(xstep);
 rgb[1] = green_value.valueAsNumber;
}
function addcolorpointblue(){
 document.getElementById("blue_value").stepUp(xstep);
 rgb[2] = blue_value.valueAsNumber;
}
```

And these are the same but these allow to subtract color:

```
//Functions to subtract value from color
function subcolorpointred(){
 document.getElementById("red_value").stepDown(xstep);
 rgb[0] = red_value.valueAsNumber;
}
function subcolorpointgreen(){
 document.getElementById("green_value").stepDown(xstep);
 rgb[1] = green_value.valueAsNumber;
}

function subcolorpointblue(){
 document.getElementById("blue_value").stepDown(xstep);
 rgb[2] = blue_value.valueAsNumber;
}
```

There is some way to generalize all these functions in one per each action(add, subtract), like this:

```
funtion addcolor(){
 if (redslider){
  /*do stuff for redslider*/
 }
 else if (greenslider){
  /*do stuff for greenslider*/
 }
 else if (blueslider){
  /*do stuff for blueslider*/
 }
```

Comment: From where you're calling this function? Can you provide HTML.?

Comment: Use function parameters. This is programming 101.

Comment: Could you add some other code (HTML, CSS) to make a working snippet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this (without using the non-standard? `stepUp`/`stepDown` functions).

```
var channelToIndex = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];

function manipulateColorPoint(channelName, direction) {
 var slider = document.getElementById(channelName + '_value');
 slider.valueAsNumber += xstep * direction;
 rgb[channelToIndex.indexOf(channelName)] = slider.valueAsNumber;
}
```

Call like

```
manipulateColorPoint('red', +1);  // red up
manipulateColorPoint('green', -1);  // green down
```